# Fabric JS loading of images sometimes not in order

Tags: fabricjs

So I have a bunch of PNG images that loads and when loaded and positioned properly makes a cue case. The problem is every time I refreshed the page sometimes some images are there sometimes not. Is there a way to like wait for certain images to load before others are added to the canvas?

I tried to use async but the result is still the same. Right now, the way I added images is just like this.

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(PK3Layer1000, function (myImg) {
    var img1 = myImg.set({
      left: 15 + 100 + 50 + 200,
      top: 5 + 20 + 80,
      //   clipPath: clip,
    });

    // canvas.add(img1);
    canvas.renderAll();
  });

  fabric.Image.fromURL(PK3Layer2000, function (myImg) {
    var img1 = myImg.set({
      left: 15 + 100 + 50 + 200,
      top: 5 + 20 + 80,
      //   clipPath: clip,
    });
    canvas.add(img1);
    canvas.renderAll();
  });

  fabric.Image.fromURL(PK3Layer3000, function (myImg) {
    var img1 = myImg.set({ left: 15 + 100 + 50 + 200, top: 5 + 20 + 80 });
    canvas.add(img1);
    canvas.renderAll();
  });

  fabric.Image.fromURL(PK3Layer4000, function (myImg) {
    var img1 = myImg.set({ left: 15 + 100 + 50 + 200, top: 5 + 20 + 80 });
    canvas.add(img1);
    canvas.renderAll();
  });

  fabric.Image.fromURL(PK3Layer5000, function (myImg) {
    var img1 = myImg.set({ left: 15 + 100 + 50 + 200, top: 5 + 20 + 80 });
    canvas.add(img1);
    canvas.renderAll();
  });

  fabric.Image.fromURL(PK3Layer6000, function (myImg) {
    var img1 = myImg.set({ left: 15 + 100 + 50 + 200, top: 5 + 20 + 80 });
    canvas.add(img1);
    canvas.renderAll();
  });

  fabric.Image.fromURL(PK3Layer7000, function (myImg) {
    var img1 = myImg.set({ left: 15 + 100 + 50 + 200, top: 5 + 20 + 80 });
    canvas.add(img1);
    canvas.renderAll();
  });
```